# Creating Dynamic Routes with file extension in nextjs13. For example /sitemap/[page].xml

Tags: next.js, next.js13, sitemap, xml-sitemap

we know to create dynamic sitemap, we can create with **/sitemap.xml/[page]/route.js**

but, i cant get how to create dynamic sitemap like **/sitemap-[page].xml/route.js**

Comment: have you taken a look at this?
https://nextjs.org/learn-pages-router/seo/crawling-and-indexing/xml-sitemaps